# Sick of the Moleskine

Tags: creative-spaces

Not technically a sound question, but I figure if I tag it as "facilitating creativity" or "location recording documentation" or somesuch I should be able to get away with it, yes?

Here goes:

In spite of the fact that I am (shudder) an iPhone owner, I still like to carry a journal around for longer-form writing sessions and diagram drawings.  For years and years I've used the in/famous Moleskine pocket friendly notebook.  Frankly, I'm tired of it.  I'm tired of getting that *oh, so you're a "writer"* look from people when I pull it out to jot down an idea.  And, yes, there's the fact that they've become oh so fashionable over the last 5 years.  And, yes, I am vain enough to be strongly affected by that.

Plus, the combination of having both terrible handwriting and large hands makes them excruciatingly frustrating to write in when standing on the subway or in the back of a table-less venue.

I want something hardcover in lined 8 1/2 x 11 that'll be able to endure permanent residence in my bag. It'd also be nice to be able to put it down on surfaces without having to worry so much about there being a drop or two of beer/water to smudge all of my precious squiggles.

So, my question is... Do you guys have any particular kinds/brands/styles of notebooks that you prefer to use?  Do you just go to staples or wherever and grab one of those 900 page ring-bound behemoths that last for years and years and years?  If not/so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Canson-brand sketchbooks](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=canson+sketc&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=canson+sketchbook#q=canson+sketchbook&hl=en&safe=active&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=shop&ei=YJzATcbQBKTmiAKokYGZAw&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=5&ved=0CDAQ_AUoBA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=8687a3ca9331bf41&biw=1159&bih=675). Can't stand lines, begrudgingly accept grids, hate spiral bindings that get crushed in bags. Hardcover, heavy paper, burly, traditionally bound, great tooth to the paper. Been sketching in them (and Moleskines) for 20 years and they're solid. But heavy.

Comment: Oooooh, and they're cheap too!  Wicked.

Comment: Whyyyy does NoiseJockey always have better answers! *punches keyboard*

Comment: @Utopia, I know, I know.  I want to know his secret...

Comment: Canson does paper for fine art prints too. Pretty good stuff!

Answer (score 5):

I think the best solution is for you to become an actual writer. Then it won't bother you anymore. When they give you the "oh, so you're a 'writer'" look you can confidently respond "Yes. Yes I am."

Comment: There aren't nearly enough books on sound design.

Comment: @James, Touche.

Answer (score 4):

You sure they aren't looking at your microphones & recorder rather than an inconsequential notebook? I can't imagine people looking at someone who is obviously a sound recordist, seeing the moleskin & thinking 'hes a writer.... quick give him the look!'

But maybe one of those grid lined books is the answer, then when they see you they can give you the 'he's a physicist/mathematician/outsider artist' look instead ;)

Comment: @Tim, Good point, but it's more for when I'm out pretending to be a 'normal' person. 

Answer (score 2):

While I'm a fan of my moleskine because it's small and gets the job done, I'm also a fan of the composition book. Particularly graph-lined composition books.

[This one](http://www.teacherdirect.com/cgi-bin/sgin0108.exe?UID=5216030820295671&T1=09000+MEA&FNM=00&UREQA=N&GEN1=&GEN0=) seems pretty cool because each page is half quadrille and half college rule so you've got your mapping, sketching, doodle area plus the dedicated area for notes.

Answer (score 1):

How about getting an iPad and using a smaller 4x3 notepad for the things you HAVE to write?

Comment: @Utopia, Ok, mister big bucks! | I tried using my iphone for that (bought ScriptWrite and PlainPaper and all that jazz.  I gotta say I miss the visceral sensation of skin on paper...  That sounds kind of pretentious doesn't it?

Comment: @g.a.harry Yeah, all the apps in the world can't replace that good old pulp.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of [Black n Red](http://www.blacknred.com/). They all have hard covers which offer both protection and a useful hard flat surface and they'll definitely protect your notes from the odd beer spillage. Maybe a bit too corporate for some peoples liking (actually I discovered them when I worked in the financial industry in London) but in terms of practicality I think they're right up there.

[alt text http://image1.euroffice.co.uk/image/Oxford-Black-n-Red-Book-Wirebound-90gsm-A4---Pack-5---B67004-B67004-h0.jpg](http://image1.euroffice.co.uk/image/Oxford-Black-n-Red-Book-Wirebound-90gsm-A4---Pack-5---B67004-B67004-h0.jpg)

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at these a while back.  Don't think they're carried in many Canadian stores though.

Answer (score 1):

I swear by those black and white "GhostWriter" (from the PBS TV show) notebooks... you can pick them up virtually anywhere (I've picked up more than a few at gas stations).

[image]
<sub>(source: [coloradoartstudio.com](http://coloradoartstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/cover.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Ahhhh, the classic.

Comment: Studio Log, 9, 22, 2008. Spock and I recorded snare today. I really wish I used a different mic...

Comment: ... after that, Uhura laid down some of that 70's soprano I like. You know the kind.  This track is really going to be retro, to say the least.

Comment: @Dave + @Utopia, Wait, you know a soundguy named Spock too.  Ok, now *that's* eerie.

Comment: lol           .

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of Rhodia pads. I used to be a moelskine guy but I switched to Rhodia when I kept wanting to tear pages out.  I used the grid based pads.  http://www.rhodiapads.com/rhodia_pad.shtml